# Working around a port 25 block for SMTP

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I have a Delphi 7 application that I wrote that I have distributed to a partner living in a faraway place. The app uses the IndyDirect IdSMTP component to send mail to a mail server which I own. The mail server itself has no issues.  The app worked fine until my friend moved. My friend ended up in a part of the world where his ISP blocks port 25. This prevents my Delphi app from sending email to my mail server.

The ISP said that they do permit port 587 as an alternative to port 25. My question is, is this a simple matter of changing the PORT property for the IdSMTP component from 25 to 587 and then recompiling the source code and giving my friend an updated .exe?  Does anyone know if the mail server needs to be reconfigured in any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the mail server needs to be reconfigured.  Right now it's listening on port 25; you need to configure it to listen on 587.  This should be fairly simple with most off-the-shelf mail servers.

As an aside, I'd suggest putting the SMTP port into a configuration file that you read from in your Delphi code; then if the port changes again, all you have to do is update the config file rather than recompiling it and resending it to your friend.  You could even get your friend to do it -- "Just open smtp.config and change '587' to 'xyz', then restart the program."

Comment: I agree with brian but I would make a small change. First I would add ability to the client to be able to connect to SMTP server with the use of multiple ports (25, 587, etc.). This however means that you change your client software in a way that if it fails to conect to the SMTP server by using one port number it tries other ones. When it manges to sucsessfully connect to SMTP server you store that port so that next time you will try with that one first (should avoid posible slowdowns when trying to always find unblocked port).

Comment: Now your server would have to be listening on all these posible ports all the time. The best thing about this solution is that it might not even need any manual configuration even when your user moves to another place.

Comment: @SilverWarior That's a good idea.  You get better flexibility and fault-tolerance all around.